# Redis Pub/Sub with Spring Data Redis: Messages arrive in wrong order

Tags: java, spring, redis, spring-data-redis

I am attempting to implement a chat using Redis publish/subscribe with Spring Data Redis.

I use the RedisTemplate to publish messages, shown below:

```
public class RedisPublisher {

    @Autowired
    private RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplate;

    public void publish(ChannelTopic channelTopic, Object channelMessage) {
        redisTemplate.convertAndSend(channelTopic.getTopic(), channelMessage);
    }
}
```

And to receive messages I have a MessageListener as shown below:

```
public class RedisConsumer implements MessageListener {

MessageSerializer serializer = new MessageSerializer();
AtomicInteger atomicInteger = new AtomicInteger(0);

@Override
public void onMessage(Message message, byte[] pattern) {

    Object obj = serializer.deserialize(message.getBody());
    if(obj != null && obj instanceof RedisMessage) {
        System.err.println("Received message(" + atomicInteger.incrementAndGet() + ") " + obj.toString());
    }

}
```

Messages are published like so:

```
final ChannelTopic channelTopic=connectionManager.subscribe("topic");
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {                
            Thread.sleep(5000);                
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                redisPublisher.publish(channelTopic, new RedisMessage(i + 1));
            }
        }
    }).run();
```

However, the received messages appear to be delivered in wrong order:

```
Received message(1) message id: 3
Received message(2) message id: 2
Received message(3) message id: 1
Received message(4) message id: 4
Received message(5) message id: 5
Received message(6) message id: 6
Received message(7) message id: 7
Received message(8) message id: 8
Received message(9) message id: 9
Received message(10) message id: 10
```

Is it possible to send/receive messages synchronously using the RedisTemplate/MessageListener provided by Spring?

The current code-base is small and can be viewed at [GitHub](https://github.com/abergz/Messaging/tree/master/src/main/java/com/messaging).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Redis PubSub is known to deliver the messages in order (guaranteed at least if you use one connection and trigger `PUBLISH`. The `PUBLISH` command returns the number of clients that were notified). The cause for the out-of-order is the way how Spring Data Redis dispatches the messages by default. The notification is handled on different threads and that's the reason. Thanks for the code, it helped me to quickly reproduce the behavior.

I can think of two possible strategies to address this issue:

1. You can however supply an executor that honors the order within `RedisMessageListenerContainer`. Right now, any form of synchronization I'm thinking of, would harm performance.
2. Implement an own message listener on top of `BinaryJedisPubSub`. You're in control over the messages and you can omit the executor issue.

HTH, Mark

Comment: In regard to `strategy #2`,  I'm not entirely sure how I would go about doing this - I seem to get Bean initialization errors whenever I include `compile("redis.clients:jedis:2.7.2")` to my `gradle.build`.

However, it _seems_ to be working after modifying the `MessageListener` so that it puts received messages into a `LinkedBlockingQueue` instead of deserializing it directly upon reception.

I'm not entirely sure whether this will guarantee that it will work all the time though?

New code is still available at [link](https://github.com/abergz/Messaging) if you would be interested.

Thank you!

Comment: There are/wee compatibility issues between jedis 2.7.x and Spring Data Redis 1.5.x (see [here](https://github.com/xetorthio/jedis/issues/1043)). One solution that comes into my mind is using a single-threaded executor (forked thread, not the main thread). Redis works mostly single-threaded so messages are not published concurrently. The single-threaded consumer can then pass the message to the thing that does further processing.

Comment: Alright!
I tried the following modification to the `RedisMessageListenerContainer`:

`ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();`


`redisContainer.setTaskExecutor(executorService);`

However, the consumer starts working only after the program is "shutting down", i.e. only prints out the first 2-3 messages (out of 100) when the stop application button in Intellij  has been pressed.

Comment: Never mind the above -  changing from a `SingleThreadExecutor` to `ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);` seems to fix the problem. My guess is that the publisher and the subscriber share the same thread pool and the active publisher thus prevent the subscriber from consuming messages. Thanks for your help!